# where to put the adverb "often": the nuance

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

I heard that you can put adverbs basically anywhere.

So, I tried to use one in an unusual way.

> Buses leave the station B often for station C.

I think usually it would be like this:

> Buses often leave the station B for station C.

I don't really understand how I can choose one when I make sentences. Could you please tell me their nuance?

Do these sentences sound similar?

> The buses leave from station A for station C often.

> The buses often leave station A for station C.

Comment: It sounds odd to use sentences about buses as examples, since buses have a regular timetable and fixed routes. To indicate that there are many buses every day to a particular destination, we would say _There are frequent buses to Station C_ or similar.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I understand!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They [adverbs] are usually placed before the main verb but after auxiliary verbs. [Source](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-time/)

You therefore put "often" the adverb before the **main verb** "leave". You usually follow this standard rule to make your writing easier to understand and read. It's better to say:

> Buses often leave **from** station A **to** station C.

Comment: But the placement of _often_ can indeed affect the meaning. In "I often go abroad for my summer holiday, but this year I'm going to Brighton", _often_ has the sense _on many occasions_. "Because of my job, I have to travel overseas very often" (frequently)